# loading json data into table using jquery

Tags: jquery

JQUERY SCRIPT

```
{
  $(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON("array.json",function(data){
    var employee_data='';
    $.each(data,function(key,value){
   employee_data +='<tr>';
   employee_data +='<td>'+value.DIVNFULLNAME+'</td>';
   employee_data +='<td>'+value.FUNCDESGDES+'</td>';
   employee_data +='<td>'+value.INDENTDATE+'</td>';
     employee_data +='<tr>';
    });
  $('#data-table').append(employee_data);

});
```

});

}

HTML

{

```
     <div id="myapp" class="container">
           <h1 align="center">Show JSON Data in Jquery Datatables</h1><br />
            <h3 align="center">Employee Database</h3><br />
            <table id="data-table" class="table table-bordered">
                 <thead>
                      <tr>
                           <th>DIVNFULLNAME </th>
                           <th>FUNCDESGDES</th>
                           <th>INDENTDATE</th>
                      </tr>
                 </thead>
            </table>
       </div>

}
```

ARRAY.JSON

{

```
   {"data":[{
          "DIVNFULLNAME":"DIRECTORATE OF INFORMATION SYSTEMS & MANAGEMENT",
          "FUNCDESGDES":"PROGRAMME MANAGER",
          "INDENTDATE":"2020-06-10 00:00:00.0"
          }
```

]
}

}

iam trying to load the data into table using JQuery
but when iam trying to load the data into the table but it is showing as undefined.
iam new to JQuery ,please suggest.

Comment: i have tired this but also it is not showing the data .

Comment: try => `data.data` in your `$.each` - you have array of object. you need to access via `dot` notation and do a loop on that to get the value of object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your JSON result is an object, not an array.

You have two options. Either you change the result to this:

```
[
    {
      "DIVNFULLNAME":"DIRECTORATE OF INFORMATION SYSTEMS & MANAGEMENT",
      "FUNCDESGDES":"PROGRAMME MANAGER",
      "INDENTDATE":"2020-06-10 00:00:00.0"
    }
    // ... other objects
]
```

Or, when you handle the response, use the `data` property for the result object:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("array.json",function(RESPONSE){
    var employee_data='';
    $.each(RESPONSE.data,function(key,value){
      employee_data +='<tr>';
      employee_data +='<td>'+value.DIVNFULLNAME+'</td>';
      employee_data +='<td>'+value.FUNCDESGDES+'</td>';
      employee_data +='<td>'+value.INDENTDATE+'</td>';
      employee_data +='<tr>';
    });
    $('#data-table').append(employee_data);
  });
});
```

I've written `RESPONSE` capitalised to underline where the error is. The `data` parameter from the ajax response function is the object which contains another `data` property where you have your array.

Comment: sorry i was missing this logic , thank you so much it worked for me .

Comment: when iam using servlet can i get data from the servlet using this logic

Comment: Hi @jyothikachapur. Glad to help. Could you mark the answer as accepted? Thank you.

Comment: i have marked as accepted, thank you for your help, please could you help me out  same as for servlet

Comment: @jyothikachapur just correction here. You have marked the other answer as accepted - i think you were meant to select this one as per your comment

Comment: Hi @jyothikachapur. You have indeed marked the other answer as accepted. If it works for you, great. The servlet approach is not in the scope of your initial question.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it. I would create a variable and use a loop to create the data. Then at the end append it to the table body.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


var a = {
  "data": [
  {
    "DIVNFULLNAME": "DIRECTORATE OF INFORMATION SYSTEMS & MANAGEMENT",
    "FUNCDESGDES": "PROGRAMME MANAGER",
    "INDENTDATE": "2020-06-10 00:00:00.0"
  },
  {
    "DIVNFULLNAME": "TESTER 1",
    "FUNCDESGDES": "TESTER 2",
    "INDENTDATE": "TESTER 3"
  }
  ]
}
 
  var employee_data = '';
  
  for(i in a.data) {
      employee_data += '<tr>';
      employee_data += '<td>' + a.data[i].DIVNFULLNAME + '</td>';
      employee_data += '<td>' + a.data[i].FUNCDESGDES + '</td>';
      employee_data += '<td>' + a.data[i].INDENTDATE + '</td>';
      employee_data += '</tr>';
  }
  
  $('#data-table tbody').append(employee_data);
  
});
```

```css
.table-bordered, th, td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myapp" class="container">
  <h1 align="center">Show JSON Data in Jquery Datatables</h1><br />
  <h3 align="center">Employee Database</h3><br />
  <table id="data-table" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>DIVNFULLNAME</th>
        <th>FUNCDESGDES</th>
        <th>INDENTDATE</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```